# HtmlUnit thorw error "define is not defined"

Tags: htmlunit

I tried to load simple page using HTMLUnit it is throwing below error

```
Enclosed exception: 
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "define" is not defined.
```

I think this is problem because of ECMA6 ? But I am not able to find any way to resolve

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt would be to ignore all javascript related Exceptions because on most web sites the interesting parts work even if some of the javascript is not executed.

`webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);` // we never want Exceptions because of javascript

Some other properties which are often useful (not directly related to your problem) are:

- `webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(30000);` // limit to e.g.30s
- `webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(300000);` // timeout to e.g. 300s = 5min
- `webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);`
- `webClient.getOptions().setPopupBlockerEnabled(true);`
- `webClient.setRefreshHandler(new WaitingRefreshHandler(...));` // limit the time for refreshes